# Rewrite language prefixes in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a multi-domain site with multiple languages.
For each domain I created there specific languages.

For example:
*Belgium*: `www.mysite.be/be_fr`
*France*: `www.mysite.be/fr_fr`

They are both French, but I split up the languages to make it possible to show other content/translations.

I would like to rewrite the URLs to `www.mysite.be/fr` and `www.mysite.fr/fr` without changing the language codes.

I guess it's easy in *.htaccess*, but I'm not that good in regular expressions, etc.

I hope somebody can help me in the right direction.

Comment: At the moment this is my (non-working) code: 

`RewriteCond $ ^be_fr/$1 [NC]  
RewriteRule ^be_fr/(.*)$ /fr/$1`

Comment: Edit your question with additional information instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that both `mysite.be` and `mysite.fr` point to the same server, and use the same http root. I am also assuming that you have enabled mod_rewrite and gave it permission to change the url in the main config file (httpd.conf or something like that).

In your http root, use the following rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

#Redirect to the correct place on an external request
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /be_fr
RewriteRule ^be_fr(.*)$ http://www.mysite.be$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /fr_fr
RewriteRule ^fr_fr(.*)$ http://www.mysite.fr$1 [R,L]

#Internally rewrite requests to the correct place
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.be$
RewriteRule ^(?!be_fr) /be_fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.fr$
RewriteRule ^(?!fr_fr) /fr_fr%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

The first two rules make sure that we are using the correct url. They only match on external requests. Make sure to change the `[R]` flag to `[R=301]` after you've tested that everything works as expected. The last two rules tests first if the url does not start with `be_fr` or `fr_fr`, then tests if the domain ends with `.be` or `.fr`, and finally rewrites the url.